# Symfony setter injection doesn't call my setter when I'm using a class from another bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am trying to inject a variable in a class setter but it doesn't work.
This is my configuration :

```
Company\CoreBundle\Services\InspectorManager\InspectorManager:
    public: true
    autowire: false

App\Helpers\GraphQl\Resolver\OrderResolver:
    autowire: false
    calls:
    - [setInspector, ['@core.inspector_manager']]
```

And Class

```
class OrderResolver
{
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var InspectorManager $inspectorManager
     */
    protected $inspectorManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @var InspectorManager $inspectorManager
     * @required
     */
    public function setInspector(InspectorManager $inspectorManager)
    {
        $this->inspectorManager = $inspectorManager;
    }
}
```

setInspector is never called. The class InspectorManager comes from another bundle from another Symfony version(2.8) and is declared this way in it :

```
core.inspector_manager:
    class: Company\CoreBundle\Services\InspectorManager\InspectorManager
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    calls:
         - [setGeolocalisation, ['@core.geolocation_service']]
```

Do you have an idea why it isn't working ? I have spend way too much time in this issue and I don't see any way to solve it.
If I run `debug:autowiring` I get the InspectorManager in it.

I already changed the autowire setting of InspectorManager and OrderResolver to true but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: You can take out the ATrequired because that won't help in this case.  How are you getting the OrderResolver?  Directly from the container?  I assume your services file is being loaded?  You verified (perhaps with a debug statement) that setInspector() is never called?

Comment: @Cerad I instanciate it myself. My services file are loaded, and I verified that it nevers goes in the setInspector

Comment: Instantiating a service using the new operator does not use the container at all.  Surprised you did not get a missing constructor argument error.  You need to pull the resolver from the container or have the container inject it into another consumer.

Comment: It's because I instanciate it with the entity manager as argument.

Comment: @Cerad Well thank you, I completly forgot that a container should not be instanciated like that and that's why it isn't working.

Comment: Yep.  And for the same reason you had to pass the constructor argument you will need to call the setter itself.  Takes awhile to understand the relationship between the container and dependency injection.  In most cases you will not want to use the new operator at all in your code except for entities.